# Modifying and excluding some elements in an array

Tags: python, list

I have an array that contains several elements with a common prefix and another array, containing a list of elements to exclude, but without the prefix. I want to remove the prefix from all the elements and to exclude those that need to be excluded. For instance:

```
fullList = ['foo-1', 'foo-2', 'foo-3', 'foo-4', 'foo-5']
exclude = ['2', '4', '6']
```

I want, as a result, `fullList` to contain just `['1', '3', '5']`. I could easily do it with a loop, but I'd rather do it with a comprehension. Currently I am doing it in two steps:

```
fullList = [element.replace('foo-', '') for element in fullList]
fullList = [element for element in fullList if element not in exclude]
```

I was wondering - is there a better way and, in particular, can I do it with in a single step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one step you can do it like so:

```
[f.replace('foo-', '') for f in fullList if all(ex not in f for ex in exclude)]
# ['1', '3', '5']
```

Or following your original logic, you can embed the first comprehension into the second one as a generator:

```
[f_trim for f_trim in (f.replace('foo-', '') for f in fullList) if f_trim not in exclude]
# ['1', '3', '5']
```

Use a set if the lists are large:

```
excludeSet = set(exclude)
[f_trim for f_trim in (f.replace('foo-', '') for f in fullList) if f_trim not in excludeSet]
```

If you are considering performance, and for better readability, you can keep two lines with the first one as a generator:

```
excludeSet = set(exclude)
trimList = (f.replace('foo-', '') for f in fullList)
[e for e in trimList if e not in excludeSet]
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of the first solution.

Comment: @bontchev - that's also a wrong solution, consider `fullList = ['foo-1', 'foo-3', 'foo-5', 'foo-7', 'foo-11', 'foo-13', 'foo-17', 'foo-19']` and `exclude = ['1', '7']`. You'd expect your result to be `['3', '5', '11', '17', '19']` but the first example will give you only `['3', '5']` as it does a full string search of each `exclude` element over each `fullList` element so `1` matches every element that has `1` in it.

Comment: Indeed, so `ex not in f` should be replaced with the stricter `not f.endswith(ex)`.

Comment: @bontchev - then you get a problem of common endings, with the same setup as as above you'll get `['3', '5', '13', '19']` because `11` ends with `1` and `17` ends with `7`. The comparison must go the other way - checking for the remainder in the exclude list - to avoid collisions. If you want to use Psidom's solution, go with his second approach which will do that. If you're interested in performance, with 1M elements in the `fullList` and 1M elements in the `except` (converted to a `set`), on my system, Psidom's #2 solution takes ~0.42s, Mr. Xcoder's ~0.46s and mine ~0.21s.

Answer (score 3):

```
fullList = ['foo-1', 'foo-2', 'foo-3', 'foo-4', 'foo-5']
exclude = ['2', '4', '6']
```

Consider this method, that only works for one-digit numbers after `foo-`:

```
fullList = list([x[-1] for x in fullList if x[-1] not in exclude])
```

If you now try to print `fullList`, you get:

```
['1', '3', '5']
```

Take note that for a string, `s[-1]` returns its last character (e.g:`'abc'[-1]` yields `'c'`).

---

Solution that also works for more than one-digit numbers after `foo-`:

```
fullList = list([x.replace('foo-','') for x in fullList if x.replace('foo-','') not in exclude])
```

Comment: Neat! The downside is that it works with single digits only. I'd also turn `exclude` into a set if it was a bigger list.

Comment: @zwer fixed. done it for more than one digit as well :)

Comment: Unfortunately, what I gave in my question was just an example; in reality I have a whole string after the common prefix, so the first solution is not acceptable. I thought about the second solution myself, but calling `replace()` twice seemed inelegant.

Comment: @bontchev calling `replace()` twice would not hurt performance.

Answer (score 1):

Following on Mr. Xcoder's trail, I'd suggest an additional optimization for maximum speed:

```
# exclude = set(exclude)  # uncomment if the exclude list is big
fullList = [x[4:] for x in fullList if x[4:] not in exclude]
# ['1', '3', '5']
```

The `4` index is derived from our upfront knowledge of the length of `foo-`. Direct slicing should be considerably faster than a function call and a search & replace procedure.

Comment: Glad that someone understands me :)